# Удаленный рабочий стол на все мониторы, но что бы каждый монитор отдельно сворачивался

Tags: windows, rdp

В стандартном виндовом RDP есть возможность запустить удаленку на все мониторы, но в этом случае она растягивается по всем мониторам.

В большинстве случаев- это то, что нужно, но бывают моменты, когда для мониторинга достаточно 1 монитора и хочется параллельно сидеть на своем ПК и в мониторить только за 1 монитором RDP.

Можно ли сделать так, что бы я мог в режиме нескольких мониторов перемещать эти окна РДП независимо друг от друга?

Например, запустил какой-то тяжелый запрос на SQL Server, который может крутится десяток минут и смотришь параллельно сериальчик на своем пк, посматривая на РДП за процессом.

Есть конечно вариант, перезапускать постоянно RDP-сессию с разными параметрами мониторов, но это неудобно...

Или может быть есть какой-нибудь альтернативный клиент для винды, который такое умеет?

Comment: У вас несколько мониторов и система видит их как один монитор?

Comment: @Sheridan нет. Проблема в том, что стандартный Windows RDP клиент при режиме "использовать все мониторы" растягивает картинку на все мои мониторы и нельзя независимо друг от друга их сворачивать.